# R DLM Forecast Error - Unused Arguments nAhead

Tags: r, forecasting

I am having an issue that I cannot wrap my head around. This code worked a week ago, and according to the documentation it should work.

I am trying to create a 2-step ahead forecast using the DLM package on the following data.

```
y
669013.51
677040.83
677968.97
677247.54
654542.07
596631.88
592673.78
573510.44
571430.01
554494.29
```

Here is the code I am using to create the forecast.

```
y         <- ts(y, start = 2003, frequency = 1)

dlmMod    <- dlmModPoly(order = 1, dV = 0.8, dW = 0.1) + 
                 dlmModARMA(ar = 1, ma = 1, sigma2 = 1)

dlmFilt   <- dlmFilter(y, mod = dlmMod)

dlmFc     <- dlmForecast(dlmFilt, nAhead = 2)
```

I keep getting the following error on dlmForecast:

```
Error: unused argument (nAhead = 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: works perfectly for me. restart R and probably update to the latest R version if you haven't already.